# Why is ContextConfiguration location different in idea and eclipse

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea

In my team we work both in Eclipse and Idea. 
That works pretty good, except for one minor issue that I can't figure out how to solve.
When setting the ContextConfiguration location in our tests and running them inside Eclipse everything works like a charm:

```
@Test(groups = { "database" })
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {" file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml" })
```

But in my Idea env I get "could not find applicationContext" error. I need to
set the location like this(project name is services):

```
@Test(groups = { "database" })
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {" file:services/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml" })
```

The project structure is like this:
parent.pom with two child poms: services.pom and other.pom. When running the test in the terminal from the service project like this:

```
mvn -Dtest=com.mytest.service.somepackage.TheTest test
```

there are no issues. I guess that since my project structure is parent-with-two-children the need of /service is necessary(The project is created by pointing out the parent pom). Is there a way to fix this? Could you please help me with a solution. 
thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use a path relative to the current working directory. Eclipse and Idea use different directories. Try to use a classpath location:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {" classpath:/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml" })
```

But I'm not sure about your classpath configuration. Typically the `src/main/webapp` will be copied to a target webapp directory. May be you need to configure it to contain the target webapp dir.

Comment: Cool this worked with a modification, had to add following to my pom for it to find the context:                                              <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.xml</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>web.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>